# What should I fix for this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)?

Tags: php

***Duplicate question answers did not help!***

It seems my site has crashed for some reason and it deals with the following code:

Some help on the fix would be great! I have tried many things and none seem to work.

It claims line 347 has the error, which is the }

class Avada_Template {
    /**
     * The class constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

```
    global $content_width;
    if ( ! isset( $content_width ) || empty( $content_width ) ) {
        $content_width = '669';
    }

    add_filter( 'body_class', array( $this, 'body_classes' ) );

}

/**
 * Detect if we have a sidebar.
 */
public function has_sidebar() {

    // Get our extra body classes
    $classes = $this->body_classes( array() );

    if ( in_array( 'has-sidebar', $classes ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * Detect if we have double sidebars.
 */
public function double_sidebars() {

    // Get our extra body classes
    $classes = $this->body_classes( array() );

    if ( in_array( 'double-sidebars', $classes ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * Returns the sidebar-1 & sidebar-2 context.
 *
 * @var  int 1/2
 * @return mixed
 */
public function sidebar_context( $sidebar = 1 ) {

    $c_pageID = Avada::c_pageID();


    $sidebar_1 = get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true );
    $sidebar_2 = get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_2_replacement', true );

    if ( is_single() && ! is_singular( 'avada_portfolio' ) && ! is_singular( 'product' ) && ! is_bbpress()  && ! is_buddypress() && ! is_singular( 'tribe_events' ) && ! is_singular( 'tribe_organizer' ) && ! is_singular( 'tribe_venue' ) ) {

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'posts_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'posts_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'posts_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'posts_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'posts_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
        }

        if ( class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) && tribe_is_event( $c_pageID ) && Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
        }

    } elseif ( is_singular( 'avada_portfolio' ) ) {

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
        }

    } elseif ( is_singular( 'product' ) || ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_shop() ) ) {

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'woo_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'woo_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'woo_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'woo_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'woo_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
        }

    } elseif ( ( is_page() || is_page_template() ) && ( ! is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) && ! is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) ) ) {

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_global_sidebar' ) ) {

            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'pages_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';

        }

    } else if( is_singular( 'tribe_events' ) ) {

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar' ) ) : '';
            $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
        }

    } else if( is_singular( 'tribe_venue' ) || is_singular( 'tribe_organizer' ) ) {

        $sidebar_1 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar' ) ) : '';
        $sidebar_2 = ( 'None' != Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar_2' ) ) ? array( Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar_2' ) ) : '';
    }

    if ( is_home() ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_archive_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_archive_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( is_archive() && ( ! is_buddypress() && ! is_bbpress() && ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && ! is_shop() ) || ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_category' ) && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_skills' )  && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_tags' ) && ! is_tax( 'product_cat') && ! is_tax( 'product_tag' ) ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_archive_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'blog_archive_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( is_tax( 'portfolio_category' ) || is_tax( 'portfolio_skills' )  || is_tax( 'portfolio_tags' ) ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_archive_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'portfolio_archive_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) || is_tax( 'product_tag' ) ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'woocommerce_archive_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'woocommerce_archive_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( is_search() ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'search_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'search_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( ( is_bbpress() || is_buddypress() ) && ! bbp_is_forum_archive() && ! bbp_is_topic_archive() && ! bbp_is_user_home() && ! bbp_is_search() ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar_2' );

        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'bbpress_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar' );
            $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar_2' );
        } else {
            $sidebar_1 = get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true );
            $sidebar_2 = get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_2_replacement', true );
        }
    }

    if ( ( is_bbpress() || is_buddypress() ) && ( bbp_is_forum_archive() || bbp_is_topic_archive() || bbp_is_user_home() || bbp_is_search() ) ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ppbress_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) && is_events_archive() ) {
        $sidebar_1 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar' );
        $sidebar_2 = Avada()->settings->get( 'ec_sidebar_2' );
    }

    if ( 1 == $sidebar ) {
        return $sidebar_1;
    } elseif ( 2 == $sidebar ) {
        return $sidebar_2;
    }

}

/**
 * Calculate any extra classes for the <body> element.
 * These are then added using the 'body_class' filter.
 * Documentation: ttps://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class
 */
public function body_classes( $classes ) {

    $sidebar_1 = $this->sidebar_context( 1 );
    $sidebar_2 = $this->sidebar_context( 2 );
    $c_pageID  = Avada::c_pageID();

    $classes[] = 'fusion-body';

    if ( is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'body_blank';
    }

    if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'header_sticky_tablet' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-tablet-sticky-header';
    }
    if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'header_sticky_mobile' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-mobile-sticky-header';
    }
    if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'mobile_slidingbar_widgets' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-mobile-slidingbar';
    }
    if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'status_totop' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-totop';
    }
    if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'status_totop_mobile' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no-mobile-totop';
    }
    if ( 'horizontal' == Avada()->settings->get( 'woocommerce_product_tab_design' ) && is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'woo-tabs-horizontal';
    }

    if ( 'modern' == Avada()->settings->get( 'mobile_menu_design' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'mobile-logo-pos-' . strtolower( Avada()->settings->get( 'logo_alignment' ) );
    }

    if ( ( 'Boxed' == Avada()->settings->get( 'layout' ) && 'default' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) ) || 'boxed' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'layout-boxed-mode';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'layout-wide-mode';
    }

    if ( is_array( $sidebar_1 ) && ! empty( $sidebar_1 ) && ( $sidebar_1[0] || '0' == $sidebar_1[0] ) && ! is_buddypress() && ! is_bbpress() && ! is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) && ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) || ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() && ! is_account_page() && ! ( get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ) && is_page( get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ) ) ) ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
    }

    if ( is_array( $sidebar_1 ) && $sidebar_1[0] && is_array( $sidebar_2 ) && $sidebar_2[0] && ! is_buddypress() && ! is_bbpress() && ! is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) && ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) || ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() && ! is_account_page() && ! ( get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ) && is_page( get_option( 'woocommerce_thanks_page_id' ) ) ) ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'side-navigation.php' ) && is_array( $sidebar_2 ) && $sidebar_2[0] ) {
        $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
    }

    if ( is_home() ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( is_archive() && ( ! is_buddypress() && ! is_bbpress() && ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && ! is_shop() ) || ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_category' ) && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_skills' )  && ! is_tax( 'portfolio_tags' ) && ! is_tax( 'product_cat') && ! is_tax( 'product_tag' ) ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( is_tax( 'portfolio_category' ) || is_tax( 'portfolio_skills' )  || is_tax( 'portfolio_tags' ) ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) || is_tax( 'product_tag' ) ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( is_search() ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( ( is_bbpress() || is_buddypress() ) && ! bbp_is_forum_archive() && ! bbp_is_topic_archive() && ! bbp_is_user_home() && ! bbp_is_search() ) {
        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'bbpress_global_sidebar' ) ) {
            if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
                $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
            }
            if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
                $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
            }
        } else {
            if ( is_array( $sidebar_1 ) && $sidebar_1[0] ) {
                $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
            }
            if ( is_array( $sidebar_1 ) && $sidebar_1[0] && is_array( $sidebar_2 ) && $sidebar_2[0] ) {
                $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ( is_bbpress() || is_buddypress() ) && ( bbp_is_forum_archive() || bbp_is_topic_archive() || bbp_is_user_home() || bbp_is_search() ) ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Main' ) && is_events_archive() ) {
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 ) {
            $classes[] = 'has-sidebar';
        }
        if ( 'None' != $sidebar_1 && 'None' != $sidebar_2 ) {
            $classes[] = 'double-sidebars';
        }
    }

    if ( 'no' != get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_display_header', true) ) {
        if ( 'Left' == Avada()->settings->get( 'header_position' ) || 'Right' == Avada()->settings->get( 'header_position' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'side-header';
        }
        if ( 'Left' == Avada()->settings->get( 'header_position' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'side-header-left';
        } elseif ( 'Right' == Avada()->settings->get( 'header_position' ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'side-header-right';
        }
        $classes[] = 'menu-text-align-' . strtolower( Avada()->settings->get( 'menu_text_align' ) );
    }

    $classes[] = 'mobile-menu-design-' . Avada()->settings->get( 'mobile_menu_design' );

    $classes[] = 'fusion-image-hovers';

    return $classes;
}

public function comment_template( $comment, $args, $depth ) { ?>
    <?php $add_below = ''; ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
        <div class="the-comment">
            <div class="avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 54 ); ?></div>
            <div class="comment-box">
                <div class="comment-author meta">
                    <strong><?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?></strong>
                    <?php printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'Avada' ), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __( ' - Edit', 'Avada' ),'  ','' ); ?><?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( ' - Reply', 'Avada' ), 'add_below' => 'comment', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-text">
                    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
                        <em><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'Avada' ); ?></em>
                        <br />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php comment_text() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

}

// Omit closing PHP tag to avoid "Headers already sent" issues.

Comment: I read the duplicate....none of it makes sense. Please help!

Comment: It says line 347 has the error but all that has is }

Comment: I read through all the parsing error question answers. Still doesn't help.

Comment: If you look at the "<li>" opening tag in your code you can see that it's not coloured correctly, which leads me to believe that you have an unbalanced amount of "<?php" and "?>" tags. Please re-check those
Edit: Also, what exactly is that function supposed to do? If you want it to dynamically render comments, you're going to have to echo your HTML as a string, not place it directly in your code

Comment: very new to this. I have no clue where to put the php tags. This is a code made for a wordpress theme. I have no way of deleting and updating the theme again. I just need to edit this code. If I navigate out of this code editor page, it only goes to the parse error

Comment: When parsing your code I'm not getting any errors. Can you post the **full** error message?

Comment: all i did was click on this php file under editor on wordpress. once i try to navigate out, it goes to a parsing error. I would ask the theme provider, I can't contact them since I have no login info for them.

Comment: Here is the full error code
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/dunkley/public_html/wp-content/themes/newAvada/includes/class-avada-template.php on line 347

Comment: Your code here does not have any error. Make sure you look at the correct file: /home/dunkley/public_html/wp-content/themes/newAvada/include‌​s/class-avada-templa‌​te.php and show us the correct line.

Comment: I will edit the code in the question again.
if you go to the website I am editing, it shows the error
http://www.dunkleyinternational.com/